# RcppArmadillo LogicalMatrix operations

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to do some logical matrix multiplication in RcppArmadillo, but I got some problems. In R, for example, one may do so in the following code:

```
times = c(1,2,3)
ti = c(times,4)

lst = c(4,5,6)


st = matrix(lst,nrow=1) %*% outer(times,ti,"<")
```

Result:

```
> st
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    4    9   15
```

Here `matrix(lst,nrow=1)` is a 1 x 3 matrix, and `outer(times,ti,"<")` is a 3 x 4 Logical Matrix:

```
> matrix(lst,nrow=1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    4    5    6 

> outer(times,ti,"<")
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] [,4]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

The RcppArmadillo version is following:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export(".vm")]]
arma::mat vm_mult(const arma::vec lhs,
                  const arma::umat rhs)
{
  return lhs.t() * rhs;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix ty(NumericVector times, NumericVector ti,NumericVector lst){

  LogicalMatrix m = outer(times,ti,std::less<double>());
  NumericMatrix st = vm_mult(lst,m);

  return st;

}
```

`vm_mult` is the vector matrix multiplication, and I define the matrix as type `umat`, which is `Mat<unsigned int>`. I got the following error when try to run via sourceCpp:

```
error: conversion from 'LogicalMatrix' (aka 'Matrix<10>') to 'arma::umat' (aka 'Mat<unsigned int>') is ambiguous
  NumericMatrix st = vm_mult(mag,m);
                                 ^
```

I also change the type to `const arma::Mat<unsigned char> rhs`, and similar error appears:

```
error: conversion from 'LogicalMatrix' (aka 'Matrix<10>') to 'arma::Mat<unsigned char>' is ambiguous
  NumericMatrix st = vm_mult(mag,m);
                                 ^
```

I check the documentation of Armadillo library, it seems there is no Logical Matrix specifically defined.

So what should I do except convert the Logical Matrix to 1,0 Integer Matrix.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265689/rcpp-sugar-for-outer), asked only hours ago, is not exactly in great shape. You may want to address that before asking some strangers for more free help.

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel This question is directly linked with previous one, as I am trying translate the R code `matrix(10^(0.75 * magnitude), nrow = 1) %*% 
    outer(times, ti, FUN = "<")` into Rcpp version. I have figured out the translation of `outer(times, ti, FUN = "<")`, but still can not finish as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out ! It turns that one needs to pass LogicalMatrix from Rcpp to arma::umat using `as<arma::umat>`.

The following code should work fine.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;



// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat ty(NumericVector times, NumericVector ti,NumericVector mag){

  LogicalMatrix m = outer(times,ti,std::less<double>());
  arma::umat rhs = as<arma::umat>(m);
  arma::vec lhs = as<arma::vec>(mag);
  arma::mat st = lhs.t() * rhs;

  return st;

}
```

Result:

```
> sourceCpp('vm.cpp')
> ty(times,ti,lst)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    4    9   15
```